# GitLab docker registry reject push with error 500

Tags: gitlab, 500-error, docker-registry

#### Summary

I have self-hosted gitlab, installed with apt. I don't have `git_data_dir` in default location (see config). I can't push docker image into docker registry, directory `<shared_path>/registry` does not exists. No migrations, no backup/restore procedure, last version.

#### Problem to solve

GitLab reject Docker image push from remote location with error 500. I'm not able to push image into my private docker registry. Have anyone idea why and how to solve it?

#### Pushing image from remote device

```
root@remote:cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine

root@remote:~/playground# docker login gitlab.mydomain.com:5050
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
root@remote:~/playground# docker build -t gitlab.mydomain.com:5050/testing/registry .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM alpine
 ---> e7d92cdc71fe
Successfully built e7d92cdc71fe
Successfully tagged gitlab.mydomain.com:5050/testing/registry:latest
root@remote:~/playground# docker push gitlab.mydomain.com:5050/testing/registry
The push refers to repository [gitlab.mydomain.com:5050/testing/registry]
5216338b40a7: Retrying in 1 second
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

#### Gitlab registry log

```
repo:/# tail /var/log/gitlab/registry/current
2020-01-21_13:46:16.49320 time="2020-01-21T14:46:16.493118369+01:00" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: authorization token required" go.version=go1.12.13 http.request.host="gitlab.mydomain.com:5050" http.request.id=fbe88f1e-ccf5-4fcd-8f3a-aa03d216388a http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=8.8.8.8 http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \(linux\))"
2020-01-21_13:46:16.49351 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2020:14:46:16 +0100] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \\(linux\\))"
2020-01-21_13:46:17.10631 time="2020-01-21T14:46:17.10627187+01:00" level=info msg="authorized request" go.version=go1.12.13 http.request.host="gitlab.mydomain.com:5050" http.request.id=7cc76f13-b5f3-4f4d-9309-d338b9c5c8b5 http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr=8.8.8.8 http.request.uri="/v2/testing/registry/blobs/sha256:c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \(linux\))" vars.digest="sha256:c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9" vars.name="testing/registry"
2020-01-21_13:46:17.10687 time="2020-01-21T14:46:17.106817596+01:00" level=error msg="response completed with error" auth.user.name=myname err.code=unknown err.detail="filesystem: open /mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/testing/registry/_layers/sha256/c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9/link: permission denied" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.12.13 http.request.host="gitlab.mydomain.com:5050" http.request.id=7cc76f13-b5f3-4f4d-9309-d338b9c5c8b5 http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr=8.8.8.8 http.request.uri="/v2/testing/registry/blobs/sha256:c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \(linux\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=2.192904ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=320 vars.digest="sha256:c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9" vars.name="testing/registry"
2020-01-21_13:46:17.10702 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2020:14:46:17 +0100] "HEAD /v2/testing/registry/blobs/sha256:c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9 HTTP/1.1" 500 320 "" "docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \\(linux\\))"
2020-01-21_13:46:17.16482 time="2020-01-21T14:46:17.164783711+01:00" level=info msg="authorized request" go.version=go1.12.13 http.request.host="gitlab.mydomain.com:5050" http.request.id=e3e752c1-442a-46b1-b7c4-3f997e6e97a6 http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr=8.8.8.8 http.request.uri="/v2/testing/registry/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \(linux\))" vars.name="testing/registry"
2020-01-21_13:46:17.16537 time="2020-01-21T14:46:17.165324403+01:00" level=error msg="response completed with error" auth.user.name=myname err.code=unknown err.detail="filesystem: mkdir /mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails: permission denied" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.12.13 http.request.host="gitlab.mydomain.com:5050" http.request.id=e3e752c1-442a-46b1-b7c4-3f997e6e97a6 http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr=8.8.8.8 http.request.uri="/v2/testing/registry/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \(linux\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=2.673484ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=171 vars.name="testing/registry"
2020-01-21_13:46:17.16554 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2020:14:46:17 +0100] "POST /v2/testing/registry/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 171 "" "docker/19.03.5 go/go1.12.12 git-commit/633a0ea838 kernel/4.19.0-6-amd64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.5 \\(linux\\))"
```

Biggest problem (if I understand it right) is:

```
filesystem: open /mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/testing/registry/_layers/sha256/c9b1b535fdd91a9855fb7f82348177e5f019329a58c53c47272962dd60f71fc9/link: permission denied
filesystem: mkdir /mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails: permission denied
```

#### Directory content

There is no `registry` dir on path

```
repo:/# ll /mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/
total 40
drwxr-x--x  10 git  gitlab-www 4096 Jan 21 14:11 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Sep 24  2018 ..
drwx------  11 git  root       4096 Dec 10 08:21 artifacts
drwx------   3 git  root       4096 Oct 24  2018 cache
drwx------   2 git  root       4096 Jul 30 10:36 dependency_proxy
drwx------   2 git  root       4096 Jul 30 10:36 external-diffs
drwx------ 259 git  root       4096 Oct 25  2018 lfs-objects
drwx------   2 git  root       4096 Dec  3  2018 packages
drwxr-x---   9 git  gitlab-www 4096 Dec 10 09:12 pages
drwx------   3 git  root       4096 Sep 24  2018 tmp
```

#### Gitlab config

```
root@repo:gitlab-ctl show-config

Starting Chef Client, version 14.13.11
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["gitlab::show_config"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - redis (0.1.0)
  - registry (0.1.0)
  - gitaly (0.1.0)
  - letsencrypt (0.1.0)
  - gitlab (0.0.1)
  - runit (4.3.0)
  - crond (0.1.0)
  - package (0.1.0)
  - postgresql (0.1.0)
  - consul (0.1.0)
  - nginx (0.1.0)
  - mattermost (0.1.0)
  - acme (4.0.0)
  - praefect (0.1.0)
  - monitoring (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...

{
  "gitlab": {
    "gitlab-shell": {
      "secret_token": "<some_hash>",
      "auth_file": "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    },
    "gitlab-rails": {
      "lfs_enabled": true,
      "lfs_storage_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects",
      "backup_path": "/mnt/data/gitlab-backup/",
      "backup_keep_time": 604800,
      "shared_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared",
      "secret_key_base": "<some_hash>",
      "db_key_base": "<some_hash>",
      "otp_key_base": "<some_hash>",
      "openid_connect_signing_key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n<some_hash>\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "gitlab_host": "gitlab.mydomain.com",
      "gitlab_email_from": "gitlab@gitlab.mydomain.com",
      "gitlab_https": true,
      "gitlab_port": 443,
      "artifacts_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts",
      "external_diffs_storage_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/external-diffs",
      "uploads_storage_path": "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public",
      "packages_storage_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/packages",
      "dependency_proxy_storage_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/dependency_proxy",
      "pages_path": "/mnt/data/git-data/gitlab-rails/shared/pages",
      "repositories_storages": {
        "default": {
          "path": "/mnt/data/git-data/repositories",
          "gitaly_address": "unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket"
        }
      },
      "trusted_proxies": [

      ],
      "db_username": "gitlab",
      "db_host": null,
      "db_port": 5432
    },
    "gitlab-workhorse": {
      "secret_token": "<some_hash>",
      "auth_socket": "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket"
    },
    "logging": {

    },
    "unicorn": {

    },
    "puma": {

    },
    "mailroom": {

    },
    "gitlab-pages": {
      "gitlab_secret": null,
      "gitlab_id": null,
      "auth_secret": "<some_hash>",
      "api_secret_key": "<some_hash>"
    },
    "external-url": "https://gitlab.mydomain.com",
    "registry-external-url": null,
    "mattermost-external-url": null,
    "pages-external-url": null,
    "runtime-dir": "/run",
    "git-data-dir": null,
    "bootstrap": {

    },
    "omnibus-gitconfig": {

    },
    "manage-accounts": {

    },
    "manage-storage-directories": {

    },
    "user": {
      "home": "/var/opt/gitlab",
      "git_user_email": "gitlab@gitlab.mydomain.com"
    },
    "gitlab-ci": {

    },
    "sidekiq": {

    },
    "mattermost-nginx": {
      "listen_port": null
    },
    "pages-nginx": {
      "listen_port": null
    },
    "registry-nginx": {

    },
    "remote-syslog": {

    },
    "logrotate": {

    },
    "high-availability": {

    },
    "web-server": {

    },
    "prometheus-monitoring": {

    },
    "pgbouncer": {

    },
    "pgbouncer-exporter": {

    },
    "storage-check": {
      "target": "unix:///var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket"
    },
    "nginx": {
      "redirect_http_to_https": true,
      "ssl_certificate": "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt",
      "ssl_certificate_key": "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.com.key",
      "proxy_set_headers": {
        "Host": "$http_host_with_default",
        "X-Real-IP": "$remote_addr",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
        "Upgrade": "$http_upgrade",
        "Connection": "$connection_upgrade",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "X-Forwarded-Ssl": "on"
      },
      "real_ip_trusted_addresses": [

      ],
      "listen_port": 443
    }
  },
  "roles": {
    "application": {

    },
    "redis-sentinel": {

    },
    "redis-master": {

    },
    "redis-slave": {

    },
    "geo-primary": {

    },
    "geo-secondary": {

    },
    "monitoring": {

    },
    "postgres": {

    },
    "pgbouncer": {

    },
    "consul": {

    }
  },
  "monitoring": {
    "prometheus": {
      "alertmanagers": [

      ],
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9090",
        "storage.tsdb.path": "/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data",
        "config.file": "/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      }
    },
    "grafana": {
      "secret_key": "7dfc8ff446078cdabd489b77ec25fa37",
      "gitlab_secret": "<some_hash>",
      "gitlab_application_id": "<some_hash>",
      "admin_password": "<some_hash>",
      "metrics_basic_auth_password": null,
      "datasources": [
        {
          "name": "GitLab Omnibus",
          "type": "prometheus",
          "access": "proxy",
          "url": "http://localhost:9090",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "alertmanager": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9093",
        "storage.path": "/var/opt/gitlab/alertmanager/data",
        "config.file": "/var/opt/gitlab/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml"
      }
    },
    "node-exporter": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9100",
        "collector.mountstats": true,
        "collector.runit": true,
        "collector.runit.servicedir": "/opt/gitlab/sv",
        "collector.textfile.directory": "/var/opt/gitlab/node-exporter/textfile_collector"
      }
    },
    "redis-exporter": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9121",
        "redis.addr": "unix:///var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket"
      }
    },
    "postgres-exporter": {
      "flags": {
        "web.listen-address": "localhost:9187",
        "extend.query-path": "/var/opt/gitlab/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml"
      }
    },
    "gitlab-exporter": {
      "probe_sidekiq": true
    },
    "gitlab-monitor": {

    }
  },
  "letsencrypt": {
    "auto_enabled": false,
    "enable": false
  },
  "package": {

  },
  "registry": {
    "health_storagedriver_enabled": false,
    "http_secret": "<some_hash>",
    "internal_certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\<some_hash>\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
    "internal_key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n<some_hash>\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  },
  "redis": {
    "rename_commands": {
      "KEYS": ""
    }
  },
  "postgresql": {
    "internal_certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n<some_hash>\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
    "internal_key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n<some_hash>\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  },
  "repmgr": {

  },
  "repmgrd": {

  },
  "consul": {

  },
  "gitaly": {
    "storage": [
      {
        "name": "default",
        "path": "/mnt/data/git-data/repositories"
      }
    ]
  },
  "praefect": {

  },
  "crond": {

  },
  "mattermost": {
    "email_invite_salt": "<some_hash>",
    "file_public_link_salt": "<some_hash>",
    "sql_at_rest_encrypt_key": "<some_hash>",
    "sql_data_source": "user=gitlab_mattermost host=/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql port=5432 dbname=mattermost_production"
  }
}

Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 06 seconds
```

#### GitLab environment info

```
repo:/# gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info

System information
System:         Debian 8.11
Proxy:          no
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.6.3p62
Gem Version:    2.7.9
Bundler Version:1.17.3
Rake Version:   12.3.3
Redis Version:  3.2.12
Git Version:    2.24.1
Sidekiq Version:5.2.7
Go Version:     unknown

GitLab information
Version:        12.6.4-ee
Revision:       cc6b787e7b0
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     PostgreSQL
DB Version:     10.9
URL:            https://gitlab.mydomain.com
HTTP Clone URL: https://gitlab.mydomain.com/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.mydomain.com:some-group/some-project.git
Elasticsearch:  no
Geo:            no
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers:

GitLab Shell
Version:        10.3.0
Repository storage paths:
 - default:      /mnt/data/git-data/repositories
GitLab Shell path:              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

Answer (score 1):

Who is the owner of your registry directory?

Try changing the owner to "registry".
I had a similar problem and changed  the owner of "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry/docker/registry/" from "git" to "registry"

Comment: Problem is, there is no `registry` directory. Not even after `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. I created it for test, changed owner and group and push still does not work.

Comment: Just one note, I had to create this directory, because without it, `gitlab-backup create` crashed with error something like `registry dir is missing`

Comment: I think it's more accurate to do `chown -R registry:git /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry`. 
I have this user:group owner in the folder but not in subfolders, this way I was able to solve the issue.
Also you can check the logs with `tail /var/log/gitlab/registry/current -n 100` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry/docker/registry/" from "git" to "registry" worked for me, appeared after Gitlab update from 15th to 14th

Comment: I can't downvote this, but what's the difference with @vahid-ghoreishi answer two years ago? you didn't add nothing relevant.